# What's the best way to debug memory leak issues?

Tags: debugging, memory

Since the memory leakage is from a running IIS service and I cant debug the code directly, My first idea was to dump the memory into a memory dump file, and then use visual studio or windbg to read it, but in some cases, I had memory leakage of 50+Gbs, so doing memory dumps would take incredible time and even loading the file would be an issue.

Anyone has good practices or methods to debug live memory issues?